# What path to write in java -classpath?

Tags: java, unix, package, classpath, maven-plugin

I have a package with many files and directories (Californium, a CoAP protocol implementation). It comes as a Maven project. I have gone to the directory of the pom.xml file and ran `mvn package` in the terminal. Everything went fine. But upon going to one of the examples (Helloworldserver.class), and trying to run it with `java HelloWorldServer` I get:

`Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldServer`.

I look at the classpath by typing `echo $CLASSPATH` and I get nothing. So I try to set the classpath:

```
java -classpath org.eclipse.californium.examples
```

Which generates a description of all the possible options available for the java command, and does NOT set the classpath.

I chose the classpath in the above command because in the HelloWorldServer.java, there is the first line:

```
package org.eclipse.californium.examples;
```

I suspect this is wrong, judging by the output of my command. How is the correct way to specify the path? What do I want to point to?

Comment: `mvn package` should have created a jar file in `target`. That may or may not include all dependencies and/or be executable. Maybe the project includes some shell scripts to run it? Or at least a README?

Comment: Ah, yes. There is a jar file. But upon running it, I get the same error but with the name of the jar file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you built the code using Maven, it will have created a "target" directory, and within that a "classes" directory tree that contains the class files produced by the compiler.

Find that "target/classes" directory or whatever it is called.  (It is called "target/classes" in the standard Maven file structure, but the POM file could specify otherwise.)

Now run the application like this:

```
  $ java -classpath target/classes:<dependency-1>:<dependency-2>:... \
        org.eclipse.californium.examples.HelloWorldServer
```

where `<dependency-1>` and `<dependency-2>` and so on are the pathnames for the dependency JAR files ... as downloaded into your local `.m2` repo by Maven.

---

The general pattern that the `-classpath` parameter is a colon-separated<sup>1</sup> list of directory names, jar/zip file names or jar/zip file patterns.  If you run against classes that have not been packaged into a JAR or ZIP file, you need to give the root of the class tree.  For instance, if the full name for your `HelloWorldServer` class is

```
    org.eclipse.californium.examples.HelloWorldServer
```

then the target directory tree will look like this:

```
  ...
  target:
    classes:
      org:
        eclipse:
          californium:
            examples:
              HelloWorldServer.class
```

The "target/classes" is the correct root directory.  The `java` command will attempt to navigate to the "HelloWorldServer.class" file based on the package naming.

Do not be tempted to do this:

```
$ java -classpath target/classes/org/eclipse/californium/examples:... \
     HelloWorldServer.class
```

It won't work.

---

<sup>1 - or a semicolon on Windows.</sup>